# Need to call CLR Table-valued UDF from a View

Tags: sql-server, clr, sql-server-2012

That doesn't sound too hard, right? But it is.

Someone has a program that will call my view with something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM view WHERE ID=6
```

The view has to pass the 6 into the `UDF` (which is written in C# and is too complex to do in T-SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM udf(6)
```

The UDF exists and works. I cannot figure out how to write the view to get the ID in its WHERE clause to be a parameter to the udf.

I'll stoop to any level to accomplish this. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot parameterize views. View expansion is entirely under the control of SQL Server and is not exposed to programmers, so there's no opportunity to examine the query within which a view is being accessed and transform parts of the `WHERE` clause into anything else. You can (as you're aware) parameterize UDFs - so that's what you're going to have to expose to users.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, wrap table-valued function into view? What are the `ID` possible values, an arbitrary `int` or fixed set value (e.g. one of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6 and nothing else)?

Comment: The problem is that the calling program is out of my control and they can only construct and execute "select * from myView where id=int" using a connection to my remote db. The set of ints is known, however. @i-one, where were you going with that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try following construct (though I think it's a bad idea):

```
create view myView
as
    select IDs.ID, f.Value
    from (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)) IDs(ID) -- possible ID values
        cross apply udf(IDs.ID) f
GO

select * from myView where ID=6
```

This approach, however, probably will be near useless if UDF has multiple parameters, and useless, if it has parameters of poorly-countable or uncountable types.

Comment: This is perfect. I will test and mark as accepted if it works. I've never heard of "cross apply". Thank you very much.